# How to properly setup Content Groupings in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, categories

On my e-commerce site I have 4 levels of categories for products (i.e. Men/T-shirt/Hawaii Style/Modern, Women/Dress/Summer, Misc). Each category/sub(*)category has designated URL.

In my reports I need to be able to see, how each category/subcategory is performing in terms of pageviews/sessions.

It is important to mention, that some sub-categories may have same names (i.e. "T-Shirt" subcategory may be under "Men" and "Women" categories). I need to track them separately as well as be able to see a roll-up.

I have a solution, but wanted to hear opinion of GA professionals if that makes sense and whether it is valid way to do it.

So I created 4 Custom Groupings: 
[image]

I am setting each of "Category Level N" Content Groupings via my tracking code. Basically, on each page I set all 4 content groupings (if available).

Since I need to have a report for distinct category paths, not just for one, I want to use custom report (Flat table) with these 4 content groupings added as dimensions. This should give me all combinations.

Does it make sense? Is ther any other way to do it?

Comment: It it works, it's ok. As you can see here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en it makes sense. If your urls are clean, you can even use url extraction or even rules based on page title. It can be easier.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any simple way to extract value of specific Query String parameter into custom dimension?

Comment: you can make an advanced filter. Extract Request URI in field a and output it in your chosen custom dimension. Let me know.